# Counting rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which returns 20 rows.

```
select year( ArticleDate )
from NewsData nd
inner join NewsCategories nc on nd.DirectNewsID = nc.DirectNewsID
where nd.Deleted = 0
and year( nd.ArticleDate ) = 2006
group by nd.DirectNewsID;
```

Is it possible to get this to return a single row with the number 20 followed by the year in the `and` section?

The end query will not contain `and year( nd.ArticleDate ) = 2006`, so it will return a single row per year with the count.  I only added the `and year( nd.ArticleDate ) = 2006` for testing purposes.

Is this possible?

Comment: `SELECT YEAR(nd.ArticleDate), COUNT(*) AS cnt ... GROUP BY nd.DirectNewsID, YEAR(nd.ArticleDate)`

Comment: That breaks a single year into too many rows.  It should be a single row per year.

Comment: Then `GROUP BY YEAR(nd.ArticleDate)` only.

Comment: @oshirowanen your question title and detail confusing others , please make it clear , as you post in comments of answers. please edit it

Comment: It is advisable to include sample data, with the results that you require.  This often allows a tangible and direct way of defining what you want without needing to know how to express the solution in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select year(nd.ArticleDate), COUNT(DISTINCT nd.DirectNewsID)
from NewsData nd
inner join NewsCategories nc on nd.DirectNewsID = nc.DirectNewsID
where nd.Deleted = 0
group by year(nd.ArticleDate);
```

*EDIT*

This now counts the distinct occurances of `nd.DirectNewsID` in each year.

Comment: That seems to break down the year into many rows, i.e. at the moment, it gave me 5 rows with 2006 and a different count next to each row.  I was after just 1 row per year with the count of all of 2006 for example.  The same for the rest of the years.

Comment: That is due to the `nd.DirectNewsID` in the GROUP BY from your original query.  Do you want to NOT group by `nd.DirectNewsID`?  If that's the case, simply remove it from both the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses of the query.

Comment: Based on a comment to another question, I think I've realised what you wanted, see the change above.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select year( nd.ArticleDate ), count(*)
from NewsData nd
inner join NewsCategories nc on nd.DirectNewsID = nc.DirectNewsID
where nd.Deleted = 0
and year( nd.ArticleDate ) = 2006
group by year( nd.ArticleDate );
```

Replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct nd.DirectNewsID)` if the objective is to determine number of DirectNewsID, instead of total number of rows.

Comment: I think you found what the (confused question meant). I bet it's the `count(distinct nd.DirectNewsID)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count` method.  See: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use count method to get the total number of rows. i.e.

```
select count(*) from NewsData nd inner join NewsCategories nc  where nd.Deleted = 0, nd.DirectNewsID =  c.DirectNewsID  and year( nd.ArticleDate ) = 2006
```

Check it.. it should work as per your need

Comment: That gives me too many rows, it should be giving me 20, and not 45.  Plus I need it to display the appropriate year next to the count too.

Comment: select year( nd.ArticleDate ),count(nd.DirectNewsID) from NewsData nd inner join NewsCategories nc  where nd.Deleted = 0 and nd.DirectNewsID =  c.DirectNewsID  and year( nd.ArticleDate ) = 2006 . try this, may be this can help you, what you need.